# Google Places API Autocomplete not working bad request

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I'm trying to use Google places API to get autocomplete.
I've checked everything:

- API keys are activated (disabled every restriction)
- I'm calling `GMSServices.provideAPIKey` and `GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey`
- Initializing the object `placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()`
- The call I'm making is:

  ```
  let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
  filter.type = .establishment
  placesClient?.autocompleteQuery(textField.text!, bounds: nil, filter: filter) { (predictionList, error) in
      if let error = error {
          print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
          return
      }
      if let list = predictionList{
          self.resultList = list
      }
  }
  ```

The error I'm getting is:

> Printing description of error: Error
>   Domain=com.google.places.ErrorDomain Code=-3 "An internal error
>   occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error
>   represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our
>   community and support page
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/support)."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An internal error occurred in the
>   Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please
>   file a report using the instructions on our community and support page
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/support).,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x608000445370 {Error
>   Domain=com.google.places.server.ErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60800024f030 {Error
>   Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=400 "(Bad Request)"
>   UserInfo={error=Bad Request, GTLRStructuredError=GMSx_GTLRErrorObject
>   0x60800024f9f0: {message:"Bad Request" errors:[1] code:400},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Bad Request)}}}}}

Has anyone else seen this problem in Xcode 8 iOS 10? Thanks

EDIT: Now it seems that some requests are working... Maybe the server is having problems?

Comment: Currently having the same issue. Yesterday I thought I had made too many requests and thus, this morning it was working fine again. I seemed to have had the same problem again with the exception that I made new API keys and enabled them. Still having the same problem, not sure how this can happen especially since I've never had these new API keys before. It just seems like such a hassle of a problem. It was working fine yesterday!